# Enhanced Ecommerce: Shopping Behavior Analysis - Update Time

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, units-of-measurement, universal-analytics

Hello I just want to ask if how long will the shopping behavior analysis updates it's data and how am i going to check if im tracking the correct amount of data. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe 30mins lag for me. it might be different depending on traffic volume. If you're not seeing data, I've found there are a number of quirks in setting the tracking up, depending on your approach.

Comment: Hello The Reluctant Coder Can you help me how to solve if i'm not seeing data? thaanks

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I don't have much time at the moment to help 1 on 1 but specifically which data is not appearing in GA please?

Comment: Can you please take a look at this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403383/google-analytics-2-set-action Thanks, I would really appreciate any help

Comment: Or this problem. They're just similar questions made by me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404932/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce

Comment: Hello The Reluctant Coder