# Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, analytics, universal-analytics

I am using Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce on my site and I encounter this specific problem.

My Checkout 3rd Step is on the same page where I am measuring my transaction.

Should I implement it like this?

```
    ga("ec:addProduct", {values_here});
    ga("ec:setAction", "checkout", {step: 3});
    ga("ec:setAction", "purchase", {values_here});
    ga("send", "pageview")
```

**Based on the Google Analytics Debugger. I can only set 1 action per send pageview. How am I going to send my checkout step 3? is this correct? Will I send double page tracking with this?**

```
    ga("ec:addProduct", {values_here});
    ga("ec:setAction", "checkout", {step: 3});
    ga("send", "pageview")

    ga("ec:setAction", "purchase", {values_here});
    ga("send", "pageview")
```

Thanks

Comment: Send an event instead of a pageview after setting the purchase action: ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action'); Here category could be "Purchase" and action could be "click". (You decide). - See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events and https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce

Answer (score 2):

Based on: [Enhanced Ecommerce](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#transaction)

I believe you can set the checkout step as part of the action data for a purchase action.

[image: Action Data]

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics always add the last step to Checkout Behavior Analysis and Shopping Behaviour Analysis Reports as Sessions with Transactions so you don't really need to add that as a step because it is not going to add any value. See screenshot for reference[image: Checkout Behavior Analysis]

[image: Shopping Behavior Analysis]